# Add a prefix and a suffix only to some of the rownames

Tags: r, string, prefix, suffix, r-rownames

I have this dataframe:

```
structure(list(Treatnent.state = c("PRE Immune Checkpoint Blockade Therapy", 
"PRE Immune Checkpoint Blockade Therapy", "PRE Immune Checkpoint Blockade Therapy", 
"PRE Immune Checkpoint Blockade Therapy", "PRE Immune Checkpoint Blockade Therapy", 
"PRE Immune Checkpoint Blockade Therapy", "PRE Immune Checkpoint Blockade Therapy (On dabrafenib+trametinib)", 
"PRE Immune Checkpoint Blockade Therapy", "PRE Immune Checkpoint Blockade Therapy", 
"PRE Immune Checkpoint Blockade Therapy", "PRE Immune Checkpoint Blockade Therapy", 
"PRE Immune Checkpoint Blockade Therapy", "PRE Immune Checkpoint Blockade Therapy (On dabrafenib+trametinib)", 
"PRE Immune Checkpoint Blockade Therapy (On dabrafenib+trametinib)"
), timepoint = c(-6, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -3, -2, 0, 0, -1, 0, 
0), Patient = c(115, 148, 208, 208, 272, 39, 42, 422, 62, 208, 
208, 39, 42, 42)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("115-031814          ", 
"148-6-5-14_S9       ", "208-3-11-15_S13     ", "208-9-10-14_S11     ", 
"272-121914          ", "39-3-31-14_S15      ", "42-10-17-14_S3      ", 
"422-092815          ", "62-10-2-13_S6       ", "MGH208_031115-1.bam ", 
"MGH208_031115-2.bam ", "MGH39_033114.bam    ", "MGH42_101714.bam    ", 
"MGH42_101714_1.bam  "))
```

with `rownames`:

```
 [1] "115-031814          " "148-6-5-14_S9       " "208-3-11-15_S13     " "208-9-10-14_S11     "
 [5] "272-121914          " "39-3-31-14_S15      " "42-10-17-14_S3      " "422-092815          "
 [9] "62-10-2-13_S6       " "MGH208_031115-1.bam " "MGH208_031115-2.bam " "MGH39_033114.bam    "
[13] "MGH42_101714.bam    " "MGH42_101714_1.bam  "
```

I want to add a prefix "X" and suffix ".bam", only for the `rownames` that **don't** start with MGH.

So for example: The rowname of the first row, `115-031814`, would become `X115-031814.bam`, and the rowname `MGH208_031115-1.bam` would not change at all.

Comment: @AndreWildberg My mistake, it's ".bam"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grepl` to check whether a string starts with `'MGH'`, then `ifelse` to apply `paste` "X" and ".bam" if it does not start with `'MGH'`. I used `trimws` because some of your rownames has whitespace.

```r
ifelse(!grepl("^MGH" , rownames(df)),
       paste0("X", trimws(rownames(df)), ".bam"),
       trimws(rownames(df)))
```

output

```r
 [1] "X115-031814.bam"      "X148-6-5-14_S9.bam"   "X208-3-11-15_S13.bam"
 [4] "X208-9-10-14_S11.bam" "X272-121914.bam"      "X39-3-31-14_S15.bam" 
 [7] "X42-10-17-14_S3.bam"  "X422-092815.bam"      "X62-10-2-13_S6.bam"  
[10] "MGH208_031115-1.bam"  "MGH208_031115-2.bam"  "MGH39_033114.bam"    
[13] "MGH42_101714.bam"     "MGH42_101714_1.bam"
```